# Style select element, but only when it's in a div that is using a certain style

Tags: css

Not sure if the title makes much sense, but here is what I'm trying to do.

```html
<div class="mystyle">
    <select name="somename" id="somename">
       <option value="Value1">
       <option value="Value2">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="myotherstyle">
     <select name="somename" id="somename">
       <option value="Value1">
       <option value="Value2">
    </select>
</div>
```

Is it possible to style the select element in the div with class "mystlye" without setting the class on the select?  I would like the select element to be styled only if it's contained in a div that has a class of "mystyle".

Something like this:

```
div.mystyle {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;  
}

div.mystyle.select {
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the dot to a space in your `div.mystyle.select` selector. `select` is a tag not a class.

```
div.mystyle {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;  
}

div.mystyle select {
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 0px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LftRc/

Answer (score 0):

Using a space says it has to be a child.

```
.mystyle select { }
```

Using the `>` operator means a direct child (e.g.., not a .select inside a div inside a div inside .mystyle).

```
.mystyle > select { }
```

You can also use "pseudo-elements" and "pseudo-classes" on the parent.

```
.mystyle:hover select { /* The .select element when .mystyle is hovered over */ }
```

It leads to some interesting results when used correctly.

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry.  You're referring to `select` instead of `.select`, correct @AlienWebguy?

Comment: Yep looks like you fixed it :)